# Pascal's Triangle with a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My assignment is make pascals triangle using a list.
I will receive the users input which is the height of the triangle and go from there.
I have a psuedo code, but I just don't know how to implement the last "Else" part where it says to find the value of "A in the triangle one row up, and once column back" and "B: in the triangle one row up, and no columns back."
This is the pseudo code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFwkT.jpg.

Thanks!

Code:

```
def pascalsTriangle():
height = int(input("Enter height of triangle:"))
t_List = []
for R in t_List(0,height+1):
    n_List = []
    if R == 0:
        n_List = [1]
    elif R == 1:
        n_List == [1,1]
    else:
        for C in R:
            if C == 0:
                n_List.append(1)
            elif C == R:
                n_List.append(1)
            else:
                A = t_List()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of lists.

```
def pascalsTriangle():
  height = int(input("Enter height of triangle: "))
  triangle = []
  row = []
  prev_row = []
  for i in xrange(0, height + 1):
    row = [j > 0 and j < i - 1 and i > 2 and prev_row[j-1] + prev_row[j] or 1 for j in xrange(0, i)]
    prev_row = row
    triangle += [row]
  return triangle[1:]
```

For example:

```
 Enter height of triangle: 5
 [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def pascal_triangle(height):
    if height < 0 : return
    # height = 0
    T = [[1]]
    # loop for the next r = [1:height+1]
    for R in range(1, height + 2):
        # c == 0
        N = [1]
        # caculate [1:r) (exclude r itself)
        for C in range(1, R):
            a = T[R - 1][C - 1]
            b = T[R - 1][C]
            # c = a + b
            N.append(a + b)
        # c == r
        N.append(1)
        T.append(N)
    # print each R, from [0, height+1], total row is height+2
    for R in T:
        # i want to a pyramid, but the last row will
        # still have a single leading space
        print ' ' * (height - len(R) + 2),
        for C in R:
            print C,
        # new line
        print


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    pascal_triangle(int(sys.argv[1]))

$ python /tmp/test.py 4
      1
     1 1
    1 2 1
   1 3 3 1
  1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

def pascal (level, acc = None):
    if not acc: acc = [[1]]
    if level == 1: return acc
    acc.append ( [1] + [a + b for a, b in zip (acc [-1], acc [-1] [1:] ) ] + [1] )
    return pascal (level - 1, acc)

print (pascal (6) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
def my_pattern(n): 
    tree = [[1]] #first row is always just 1
    for x in range(1, n): #for every other row:
        m = [1] #it always starts with 1
        for y in range(1, x): #for all the others:
            m.append(tree[x-1][y-1] + tree[x-1][y]) #work out what the number is
        m.append(1) #it always ends in 1
        tree.append(m) #add the row on
    return tree
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd make a list for the triangle, containing lists that each represent a row. These rows can be generated recursively.

```
height = int(input())

def pascal(h, nums): # Height and array of current triangle
  if h == 1: # finished!
    return nums

  next_row = [1]# Start row

  # Iterate through the last row
  for i in range(len(nums[-1]) - 1): 
    # Append each item in the last row addded to the item on the right
    next_row.append(nums[-1][i] + nums[-1][i + 1])

  next_row.append(1) # End row

  nums.append(next_row) # Add row to triangle

  return pascal (h - 1, nums) # Repeat at next row


# Start the recursion with the top of the triangle
triangle = pascal(height, [[1]]) 
print triangle
```